# How to Add Custom Fields to Custom Taxonomies in Wordpress CLEANLY

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

Saving extra fields that were added to a taxonomy.  I want the most proper & efficient way of doing so.  **Where should I save the new fields?**

2 possible solutions are to

1)  Use the Wordpress options table as described here... [Add Custom Fields to Custom Taxonomies](http://sabramedia.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies).  This is admittedly "not clean" and assumed not to be the correct answer.

```
// A callback function to save our extra taxonomy field(s)
function save_taxonomy_custom_fields( $term_id ) {
if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
    $t_id = $term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" );
    $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
        foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ){
        if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ){
            $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
        }
    }
    //save the option array
    update_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id", $term_meta );
}
}
```

2)  Add a new table as described here [Custom Taxonomies in Wordpress](http://www.codehooligans.com/2010/07/07/custom-meta-for-new-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/) which follows the naming convention of 'wp_' + customtaxonomykey + 'meta'.

3)  Some other option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 2 is the cleanest method - which I've also used a number of times. Unfortunately, there is no default term_metadata table in WordPress yet. This post also covers the same approach, http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-term-or-taxonomy-meta-data

And of course, there's a plugin for that too :) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/

Comment: Great tutorial link.  So easy!  Thank you.  (of course I wanted to roll my own as plug ins are too easy of a solution!)

Answer (score 14):

**You can save attachment id in options table and get to display that attachment**

There are three main functions to add the meta box for taxonomy.Which are invoked through following hooks:

1. **{taxonomy_name}**_add_form_fields
2. **{taxonomy_name}**_edit_form_fields
3. edited_**{taxonomy_name}**
4. create_**{taxonomy_name}**

Here you can change the taxonomy_name with any predefined or custom taxonomy accordingly. I am using “Woocommerce product taxonomy” and created a plugin for same. Please review following functions to add custom field:

{taxonomy_name}_add_form_fields add new custom field to add new term page form.Here I am creating a field to add a Class for term.

Add the following code in functions.php in your theme

```
public function mj_taxonomy_add_custom_meta_field() {
            ?>
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="term_meta[class_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Add Class', 'MJ' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="term_meta[class_term_meta]" id="term_meta[class_term_meta]" value="">
                <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','MJ' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'mj_taxonomy_add_custom_meta_field', 10, 2 );
```

{taxonomy_name}_edit_form_fields add a field on term edit page

```
public function mj_taxonomy_edit_custom_meta_field($term) {

        $t_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" ); 
       ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="term_meta[class_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Add Class', 'MJ' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="term_meta[class_term_meta]" id="term_meta[class_term_meta]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['class_term_meta'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['class_term_meta'] ) : ''; ?>">
                <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','MJ' ); ?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }

add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields','mj_taxonomy_edit_custom_meta_field', 10, 2 );

public function mj_save_taxonomy_custom_meta_field( $term_id ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {

            $t_id = $term_id;
            $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
            $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
            foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
                if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
                    $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
                }
            }
            // Save the option array.
            update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
        }

    }  
add_action( 'edited_product_cat', 'mj_save_taxonomy_custom_meta_field', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_product_cat', 'mj_save_taxonomy_custom_meta_field', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Could you please [edit your answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/255701/edit) and add in a bit of information on what this code does and how it solves the original issue?

Answer (score 3):

## 1) Default `wp_options` table

I really don't understand why folks propose

```
update_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id", $term_meta );
```

when we can have one single option, whose indexes are the Term ID and the custom fields as values

```
$options = get_option( 'taxonomy_term_meta' );
$options[$t_id] = $term_meta;
update_option( 'taxonomy_term_meta', $options );
```

and then simply pull the option and get the value stored for a given Term ID

```
$options = get_option( 'taxonomy_term_meta' );
echo $options[$tax->term_id];
```

## 2) Custom `wp_taxonomymeta` table

That's what the plugin [Taxonomy Metadata](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/), linked by James, does. And it's quite simple, once this table is created, the functions `add_`, `get_`, `update_` and `delete_metadata` will start working with `'taxonomy'`. Like so:

```
function add_term_meta($term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false) {
    return add_metadata('taxonomy', $term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
}

function delete_term_meta($term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value = '') {
    return delete_metadata('taxonomy', $term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
}

function get_term_meta($term_id, $key, $single = false) {
    return get_metadata('taxonomy', $term_id, $key, $single);
}

function update_term_meta($term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value = '') {
    return update_metadata('taxonomy', $term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);
}
```

## 3) Helper Post Type

As described in [Matthew Boynes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56760/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-cleanly/119627#119627) answer (I think someone mentions this too in the ticket #10142.

## 4) Outside the Box

In the [plugin code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/taxonomy-metadata/tags/0.3/taxonomy-metadata.php), there's a link to the [Core Ticket #10142](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10142) discussing all this. It's a 4 years old ticket, `(closed)(maybelater)`, lots of developers jumped in, but no conclusion was reached.

By the end of it, we have this nugget (my emphasis):

> [image: paco pepe]
>   As I need this regularly, I've wrote my own solution: **Misuses the "description" field as storage container for a serialized array. The only thing that was a little tricky was to display the plain description in the admin UI.** Anyway this would be the solution I was hoping for: Simply convert the description field instead of adding a bunch of new fields. If there's a need for it, then we will see the use cases after we got it and move for a searchable solution with a later version.

***Pretty*** clever.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is **(3) Some other option**.

This is a little unconventional, but it scales the best, leverages core the most, and doesn't require adding a database table: **Add a hidden post type for the taxonomy.** Each term in the taxonomy gets its own post in the post type. With that in place, the term meta can be stored as post meta. [Here's an example of using this approach](https://github.com/alleyinteractive/wordpress-fieldmanager/blob/master/php/util/class-fieldmanager-util-term-meta.php).

The main issues with any other approach (including the "use the term's description field to hold serialized data" option) are scalability, performance, and compatibility.

Comment: Well remembered, I'll change my numbering.

Comment: Not just with a custom post type hidden. If a term happens to be associated with a single post, a post or page type. Then the term meta can store that posts ID and we can create a lot of custom fields for that post that exist to have a relationship with a term in our custom taxonomy. Whatever your approach. I highly recommend creating some protection from the deletion of custom terms if they hold so much meta and are linked to posts. I'm doing that in WP e-Customers now because deleting a term could create havok if the meta for the term is needed and in use.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/

You can customized through above mentioned plugin..